# Detect source language at runtime from within debugging visualizer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am writing a [debugging visualizer for Visual Studio](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString#visual-studio-debugger-visualizer-for-expression-trees) that renders expression trees into C# or VB.NET pseudo-code.

I want that the default rendering language should match that of the current debugging window.

Also, I want to add functionality to generate a Watch expression for a given node in the expression tree; this requires knowing which language is currently being debugged.

**How can I detect from within the visualizer code which language is currently being debugged?**

(I"m assuming this isn't possible from arbitrary runtime code, as the code is compiled down to IL.)

([Project issue](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString/issues/2))

Comment: If you have access to the raw source in the debugging window, you could try running Roslyn, and for each language, check if the source is accepted.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @dymanoid and @Homer Jay **final** version is:

```
public enum SourceLanguage
{
    Unknown, // probably C# for it's the only language without any particular symptom
    VB,
    FSharp,
    Cpp
}

static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Assembly, SourceLanguage> cache = new Dictionary<Assembly, SourceLanguage>();

    public static SourceLanguage GetSourceLanguage(this Type type) => type.Assembly.GetSourceLanguage();

    public static SourceLanguage GetSourceLanguage(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        if (cache.TryGetValue(assembly, out var sourceLanguage))
            return sourceLanguage;

        var name = assembly.GetName().Name;
        var resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        var assemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(a => a.Name);
        var types = assembly.DefinedTypes;

        if (assemblies.Contains("Microsoft.VisualBasic") &&
            resources.Contains($"{name}.Resources.resources"))
            sourceLanguage = SourceLanguage.VB;
        else if (assemblies.Contains("FSharp.Core") &&
                 resources.Contains($"FSharpSignatureData.{name}") &&
                 resources.Contains($"FSharpOptimizationData.{name}"))
            sourceLanguage = SourceLanguage.FSharp;
        else if (types.Any(t => t.FullName.Contains("<CppImplementationDetails>.")))
            sourceLanguage = SourceLanguage.Cpp;
        else
            sourceLanguage = SourceLanguage.Unknown;

        cache[assembly] = sourceLanguage;

        return sourceLanguage;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

If one has types `CSType`, `VBType`, `FSType` and `CppType` created with `C#`, `VB.NET`, `F#` and `C++/CLI` respectively

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Dictionary<SourceLanguage, string> dict = new Dictionary<SourceLanguage, string>()
    {
        [SourceLanguage.Unknown] = "C#",
        [SourceLanguage.VB] = "VB.NET",
        [SourceLanguage.FSharp] = "F#",
        [SourceLanguage.Cpp] = "C++/CLI"
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format($"Entry assembly source language: {dict[Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetSourceLanguage()]}"));
        foreach (var t in new[] { typeof(CSType), typeof(VBType), typeof(FSType), typeof(CppType) })
            Console.WriteLine($"{t.Name} source language: {dict[t.GetSourceLanguage()]}");
    }
}
```

results into

```
Entry assembly source language: C#
CSType source language: C#
VBType source language: VB.NET
FSType source language: F#
CppType source language: C++/CLI
```

**For more details see edits.**

Comment: Even though it's perfectly possible to reference each language DLL from any source project, this nswer is probably good enough for my purposes.

Comment: @Zev Spitz, glad to hear that.

Comment: Did you not get the literal **(C++/CLI)** in the comment of your C++ manifest?

Comment: @Homer Jay, in my case the comment was just `// Metadata version: v4.0.30319`, no mention of `C++/CLI`. It depends on compiler I suppose. But your tip got handy.

Comment: Even though the bounty period is over, I would suggest you condense this answer a little. All you are saying, is if there's a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and a resource named something like `*.Resources,resources", then we can assume it's VB; if if has a reference to `FSharp.Core` and resources like `FSharpSignatureData.*` and `FSharpOptimizationData.*`, then it's F#; if any of the types have the special C++/CLI name `CppImplementationDetails` then it's C++; otherwise it's unknown. Everything else in your answer (aside from the code of the extension method) is a little extraneous.

Answer (score 5):

The Visual Studio [Custom Visualizer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/visualizer-api-reference?view=vs-2019) is pretty concise. It doesn't provide any way to get additional information about the code being debugged.

Indeed, you could go the way proposed by @Alex. However, there are some drawbacks. E.g. you might need to manually load the assembly being debugged (into a temporary `AppDomain`). Furthermore, this way is not really reliable because it's perfectly allowed for an assembly implemented in C# to reference the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly.

For a more generic and safe approach, you could use the [Visual Studio Debugger API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop).

Here is an idea how to implement this:

- Implement the [`IDebugEventCallback2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/reference/idebugeventcallback2?view=vs-2019) interface; the Visual Studio Debugger will notify your code using the `IDebugEventCallback2.Event` method.
- Obtain an [`IVsDebugger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsdebugger?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) instance.
- Call the `IVsDebugger.AdviseDebugEventCallback` method providing your `IDebugEventCallback2` implementation as an event sink.
- In your `Event` method, check for `IDebugBreakpointEvent2` - this is when the process being debugged hits a break point; you might need to use `QueryInterface` to check that - see [Note for Callers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/reference/idebugevent2?view=vs-2019).
- When a break point is hit, use the provided `IDebugThread2` instance to obtain an `IEnumDebugFrameInfo2` object, see [`IDebugThread2.EnumFrameInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/reference/idebugthread2-enumframeinfo?view=vs-2019).
- Call the `IEnumDebugFrameInfo2.Next` method to get a [`FRAMEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/reference/frameinfo?view=vs-2019) structure.
- From that structure, obtain an `IDebugStackFrame2` instance ( the `m_pFrame` field) and use its [`GetLanguageInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/reference/idebugstackframe2-getlanguageinfo?view=vs-2019) method to obtain the language that implements the code at the current break point.

A long way, yes. But definitely the (maybe only) reliable one.

---

### Update

Despite the Visual Studio Debugger API referenced above looks like native code, you can easily use it in managed code too. This API is based on COM, and the .NET platform fully supports it. You can either install the Visual Studio SDK or just use the corresponding NuGet packages, e.g. [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.11.0/). By adding those packages, you obtain the managed wrappers for the COM types and can use them in your code as if they were pure managed C# types.

For the documentation, take a look on [Visual Studio debugger extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/visual-studio-debugger-extensibility?view=vs-2019). You can also check out the [Visual Studio SDK samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples) on GitHub.

Comment: __this way is not really reliable because it's perfectly allowed for an assembly implemented in C# to reference the__ `Microsoft.VisualBasic` __assembly__
That makes sence. My up-vote.

Comment: Though it doesn't seem to be a common practice. One also can investigate assembly manifest to find out some language-specific fingerprint.
E.g. VB.NET library `SomeVBLibrary` referes to resource of name `SomeVBLibrary.Resources.resources` and F# library `SomeFSLibrary` referes to resource `FSharpSignatureData.SomeFSLibrary` and `FSharpOptimizationData.SomeFSLibrary`.
Just adding a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` doesn't seem to affect F# library resources.

Comment: 1) Can I use the VS Debugger API from managed code? 2) Could you suggest some walkthroughs or tutorials for getting started with this API?

Answer (score 2):

One should take into account that there is another possibility. The assembly could be written in C++/CLI.

But this interestingly simple. It is stated in the manifest. Everything else in the C++/CLI manifest is identical with the C# version.

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319 (C++/CLI)
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
...
}
...
```